# How to handle this to point to the upper most enclosing fn?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have a fn like this:

```
var test = (function() {
     var self = this;
     var a = function() {  (function() { self.b() })() }
     var b = function() { console.log("hello") }
     return { a:a,b:b }
})();
```

`test` `a` function calls the `b` function inside an another function. However I retained the `this` as `self`, still I'm getting issue:

`test.a()`

```
Uncaught TypeError: self.b is not a function(anonymous function) @ VM246:4a @ VM246:4(anonymous function) @ VM247:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ (program):883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ (program):816InjectedScript.evaluate @ (program):682
```

Where I'm making mistake? Why the `self` isn't retaining the `this`?

How to solve this issue?

#### Note

Changing the function to this:

```
var a = function() {  (function() { b() })() }
```

this works. However I don't want to this way, because, imagine now I'm testing the function `a` calls function `b`. Now I want to spy `b`, if I do :

```
var spyb = sandbox.spy(test,"b")
```

and call:

```
test.a()
```

in the test code if I try to do the assertion:

```
assert(b.calledOnce)
```

this fails, as spy lib couldn't able to figure out `test` `b` fn is called.

So kindly help me to get the `self` way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` within the anonymous function you use to build `test` is either `undefined` (in strict mode) or the global object (in loose mode); neither is what you want.

You don't need an object reference at all to call `b` from `a`:

```
var test = (function() {
     var a = function() {  (function() { b() })() }
     // No need for an object -----------^
     var b = function() { console.log("hello") }
     return { a:a,b:b }
})();
```

Since `a` is a closure over the context of the call to the anonymous function, it has an enduring reference to `b` (as `b` does to `a`).

But if you want to use one, you could do this:

```
var test = (function() {
     var obj = {
        a: function() {  (function() { obj.b() })() },
        b: function() { console.log("hello") }
     };
     return obj;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, say me one thing, now I do `var a = function() {  (function() { b() })() }`, but if I try to mock `b` using simon lib, always the real `b` fn is called, not the mock! Any idea, why this happens? This makes the code really un-testable

Comment: @batman: Because `a` has a reference to `b`, not to the `b` property on the object you return. So if you *replace* the `b` on the object, `a` will still call the original one. For your scenario, the second example may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

when you return 
{a:a,b:b,c:self}
you would see 'self == window' is true, so the self is point to window.

but declare variables 'b' in function use 'var' ,  the scope of 'b' is in the function , not the window , so 'self' cannot reach the variables 'b'.

the correct is :

```
var test = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.a = function() {  (function() { self.b() })() }
  self.b = function() { console.log("hello") }
  return { a:self.a,b:self.b }
};
var q = new test();
q.a(); //hello
```